# Hedera chain Unable to connect to Network using @hashgraph/sdk

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

Im following the [official documentation](https://docs.hedera.com/) and trying to play around wit Hedera Chain, I'm not able to execute any query it just gives timeOut error.

```
    //Verify the account balance

    const client = Client.forTestnet()
    const accountBalance = await new AccountBalanceQuery()
        .setAccountId(hederaUtils.operatorInfo.OPERATOR_ID)
    .execute(client);
```

Error Message:

```
max attempts of 10 was reached for request with last error being: GrpcServiceError: gRPC service failed with status: UNAVAILABLE
```

Stack:

```
at AccountBalanceQuery.execute (/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/Executable.cjs:666:11)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)\n    
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:526:9)\n    
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)\n
```

Comment: Does your package.json reference the most recent version of the [Hedera JavaScript SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hashgraph/sdk)?